# printing what is between two XML tags in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using element tree, for example Ive this XML code

```
<TEXT>
<PHRASE>
<CONJ>and</CONJ>
<V>came</V>
<en x='PERS'>Adam</en>
<PREP>from</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>Atlanta</en>
</PHRASE>
<PHRASE>
<en x='ORG'>Alpha</en>
<ADJ y='1'>Amazingly</ADJ>
<N>created by</N>
<en x='PERS'>John</en> 
</PHRASE> 
</TEXT>
```

What I want is to print the whole Phrase when I have ORG="Alpha" in **en** tag and PERS="John" in the other **en** tag, I want the output to be ***"Alpha Amazingly created by John"***

I know how to search for Alpha and John, but my problem is printing what's in between

```
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
      if (ens["ORG"] =="Alpha" and ens["PERS"]=="John"):
          print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(ens["ORG"], ens["PERS"]))
```

but how do I print the rest of tag's text in that phrase.

Comment: [This is probably relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) or try looking at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<TEXT>
<PHRASE>
<CONJ>and</CONJ>
<V>came</V>
<en x='PERS'>Adam</en>
<PREP>from</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>Atlanta</en>
</PHRASE>
<PHRASE>
<en x='ORG'>Alpha</en>
<ADJ y='1'>Amazingly</ADJ>
<N>created by</N>
<en x='PERS'>John</en> 
</PHRASE> 
</TEXT>
'''

def section(seq, start, end):
  returning = False
  for item in seq:
    returning |= item == start
    if returning:
      yield item
    returning &= item != end

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
      if (ens["ORG"].text =="Alpha" and ens["PERS"].text=="John"):
          print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(ens["ORG"].text, ens["PERS"].text))
          print(' '.join(el.text for el in section(phrase, ens["ORG"], ens["PERS"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<TEXT>
    <PHRASE>
        <CONJ>and</CONJ>
        <V>came</V>
        <en x='PERS'>Adam</en>
        <PREP>from</PREP>
        <en x='LOC'>Atlanta</en>
    </PHRASE>
    <PHRASE>
        <en x='ORG'>Alpha</en>
        <ADJ y='1'>Amazingly</ADJ>
        <N>created by</N>
        <en x='PERS'>John</en>
    </PHRASE>
</TEXT>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

for node in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = [node.find('en[@x="ORG"]'), node.find('en[@x="PERS"]')]

    if all([i is not None for i in ens]):
        if 'Alpha' in ens[0].text and 'John' in ens[1].text:               
            print (" ".join(node.itertext()))
            # If you want remove eol (end of line chars) for each item:
            # " ".join([t.strip() for t in node.itertext()])
            break
```